# MacBook Pro - Mechanical Popping/Clicking Sound

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, services, warranty

I keep on getting this Popping/Clicking sound randomly throughout regardless of whether the speaker is on or not. The sound seems to be coming from the physical machine, perhaps the screen or the motherboard-—it is not coming from the speaker.

I did the AppleCare warranty, which they simply stated they could not reproduce the said popping/clicking sound.

This issue had been posted in the Apple.com discussion, and no solutions. There are people saying Apple monitors the discussion forum and delete those posts.

This is frustrating. Does anyone experience this and/or know how to fix this issue?

My extended AppleCare ended after they returned the item to me saying they could not reproduce the said problem.

Comment: I did reset to manufacturing setting, but the problem still persists.

Comment: Does it repro if headphones are plugged in… either through the headphones or still from the Mac itself?

Comment: Thank you. it still has sound. From the Mac itself. Please let me know what you think! Thanks.

Comment: Could it be this issue? https://appleinsider.com/articles/19/12/07/apple-confirms-16-inch-macbook-pro-popping-sound-is-software-issue
I see it related to system load, I hope apple has finally patched this in a new release of Bigsur...